# How do I get my D3 map to zoom to a location?

Tags: jquery, zooming, d3.js, pan

I'm working with D3 and so far I've been able to tweak the chloropleth example to only draw a specific state. This involved simply removing all the other polygon data so that I'm left with the state I need.

I started with this:
[image]

and then tweaked things to this:
[image]

However, what I'd like to do is to auto pan/zoom the map upon creation so that the state is front and center on the display, like this:
[image]

Do I do this through the D3 library? or some independent code (I currently have jquery-svgpan running with d3 to allow for manual panning/zooming) in order to make this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to approach this, that I've found, is to set a transform on the `g` element enclosing the states (`#states` in the example), based on the bounding box of the state you're zooming to:

```
// your starting size
var baseWidth = 600;

d3.selectAll('#states path')
    .on('click', function(d) {
        // getBBox() is a native SVG element method
        var bbox = this.getBBox(),
            centroid = [bbox.x + bbox.width/2, bbox.y + bbox.height/2],
            zoomScaleFactor = baseWidth / bbox.width,
            zoomX = -centroid[0],
            zoomY = -centroid[1];

        // set a transform on the parent group element
        d3.select('#states')
            .attr("transform", "scale(" + scaleFactor + ")" +
                "translate(" + zoomX + "," + zoomY + ")");
    });
```

There's a lot more you can do here to clean it up - give some margin to the final zoom, check whether you should base the zoom on width or height, change the stroke width depending on zoom, animate the transition, etc - but that's the basic concept.

Comment: Excellent! I found some of the transform code the other day on the D3 site and that has helped with my national view, but I'll work this in to my individual state views and let you know.

Comment: How would I call my scale/transform after the d3 has finished loading the map? I'll know the specific path I need to get the bounding box for (I'm applying Ids) and I'd like to immediately get the larger view instead of relying on a click event. Since I'm only rendering a single path, could I use the .enter method instead of .on? I'm still getting used to D3

Comment: You could, but generally this would be something you'd do on update, since you'd need to do it again any time you wanted to change the state or zoom out.